# PHP - Loaded Page with Ajax/jQuery - Get URL of master page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url, path

On on my webpages (100+ different pages) on my site I have the following code to load and request a page using Ajax and jQuery. An example page url that calls this is `products.php` and `faqs.php`

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    new Ajax.Request('dynamic-page.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        requestHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },
        onSuccess:function(transport) {
            var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
            // do something with response
        }.bind(this)
    });
});
```

Now in my `dynamic-page.php` I have several conditional statements, one of which requires to know what the page that called it is.

In dynamic-page.php I can get the path:

```
$path = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And understandably this gives me the url for the dynamic page (i.e `http:www.website.com/dynamic-page.php`)

My question is within my dynamic page, is it possible to get the url/path of the master parent/page that it was called from using PHP? I need to know within my dynamic page whether the page the user is on is either `products.php` or `faqs.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to send the current page's URL as a Parameter to your Ajax Call. Try something like this, instead:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
new Ajax.Request('dynamic-page.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    requestHeaders: { Accept: 'application/json' },
    parameters: {url: window.location.href},    //the URL of the Current Page incl. query strings
    onSuccess:function(transport) {
        var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
        // do something with response
    }.bind(this)
});
```

});

At the endpoint PHP file ("dynamic-page.php" - in this case), you might do something like this:

```
<?php
    $originationURL = (isset($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['url'])) ? $_POST['url'] : "a-default-page.php";
    //Do whatever you wish with the *$originationURL* variable...
?>
```

If you are posting other data (say, form-data) with your AJAX call; be sure none of the parameters is named url.

I hope this helps... 
I didn't test the code but I think this should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

if you're requesting the page via AJAX, it counts as a separate request, so I can't see how on the server-side you could know that without extra info. However, since you're requesting the page via a POST request, the most obvious thing I can think to do is put the name of the page in the POST variables when you make the AJAX request. The page you're requesting can then use that info to know in what context it's being requested.